# prevent direct access to form post function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to create a web application. The problem I am having is with the function for submitting the form. What I want to do is to prevent direct access from URL by using the function in the form, So if anyone copy the action method from the form and enter access it by the URL, it will deny the access.

Please guide me through this.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, doing something like `if($_POST)` or `if($this->input->post())` will work in 90% of cases, they aren't 100% correct. Why not? Well, if you have a post where the person has triggered the form without actually filling anything out, they will still `POST`.

If you really want to make sure that someone is `POST`ing to your controller, you need to check the `REQUEST_METHOD`.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    // this is a POST
}
else
{
    show_404('not-a-POST!');
}
```

All of that said, there are *very* few times when limiting to `POST` is the best option. Realistically you should be handling `GET` and `POST` gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if( $this->input->post(null)){
    //your form submit code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply check the $_POST variable to do this,

```
if(!is_array($_POST) || count($_POST)==0)
{
   die('You have no access');
}
```